# undefined method `[]' for "image":Sass::Script::Value::String in rails 5.0.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
  While upgrading from rails 3 to rails 5 facing issue?

  'undefined method `[]' for "image":Sass::Script::Value::String'
   Used gem 'sass-rails'
```

No compatible syntax for image URL in rails 5

Also tried

```
asset-url("rails.png", image) 

 asset-url("rails.png")

 asset_url

 image_url

 image-url

 asset-url

 image: asset_url("back.png");

 { background-image: url("back.png"); }

 background-image: image_url('metal_texture.jpg')

 asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot", font);

 image-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot", font);
```

Even issue not yet resolved